# doc.save() is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I'm attempting to update a Mongo document using the .save() method, but it continually outputs `doc.save() is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
// cart.js

const Cart = require('../models/Cart'); //Contains the requirements for Mongoose

// My React app handles all the changes to the cart and then passes
// in the updated cart along with the customerID from the body

const doc = await Cart.find({ customerID }); // customerID = '12345'
doc.cart = cart;
doc.save();
```

Contents of cart:

```
]
  {
    name: 'Item Name',
    sku: '2233',
    price: 14.99,
    qty: 1
  }
  {
    name: 'Item Name 2',
    sku: '4455',
    price: 13.99,
    qty: 2
  }
]
```

Current response from Mongo when `console.log(doc)` is ran:

```
{
   _id: ##################,
   cart: [
     {
       name: 'Item Name',
       sku: '2233',
       price: 14.99,
       qty: 1
     }
   ],
   customerID: '12345',
   date: 2020-03-04T20:49:05.761Z,
   __v: 0
}
```

Expected output if `console.log(doc)` is ran after saving process:

```
{
   _id: ##################,
   cart: [
     {
       name: 'Item Name',
       sku: '2233',
       price: 14.99,
       qty: 1
     }
     {
       name: 'Item Name 2',
       sku: '4455',
       price: 13.99,
       qty: 2
     }
   ],
   customerID: '12345',
   date: 2020-03-04T20:49:05.761Z,
   __v: 0
}
```

Console Output when function is called: `doc.save() is not a function`

Perhaps it's because I've been coding for 8 hours, but I'm failing to see what I'm missing. Help.

Comment: An awaited `find` returns an array. Try `findOne` instead.

Comment: That worked. Man, after a long day even the simplest stuff is difficult. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An awaited `find` returns an array. To get a single document, use `findOne`:

```
const doc = await Cart.findOne({ customerID });
```